# org.json.JSONException: No value for children

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the data from the json file from reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/.json). But I keep getting the same error:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for children

this is my code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json";

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
      JSONArray children =  response.getJSONArray("children");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Log.i(TAG, "ERROR !!!!" + e);
    }
  }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ERROR");
      }
});

queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

If someone can help me it would be nice!

Comment: Right, because `children` `JSONArray` is inside `data` `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this as `children` is child of `data` object

```
JsonObject data = response.getJsonObject("data");
JsonArray children = data.getJsonArray("children");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this as your **children** Array is inside your **data** object

```
  JSONObject data =  response.getJSONObject("data");
   JSONArray children =  data.getJSONArray("children");
```